# Running an HTTP request after a few HTTP requests have completed

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a jmeter test that does an HTTP request and after a certain amount needs to run a clean up HTTP request. How can I accomplish something like this is jmeter? Currently I have a HTTP request and  I would like to implement something where after 10 HTTP requests of the first POST I run this cleanup request to remove a dependency that the first one has.

Steps:

1. POST request #1
2. Follow step 1 - 9 more times
3. POST request #2

I need to be able to run 100 concurrent users doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how your cleanup request relates to running multiple concurrent users.  Assume you have just two concurrent users and they're named Amy and Bob.  Let's say Amy sends 5 requests and then Bob sends 5 requests.  After that, do you need to send a cleanup request?  Or do you send a cleanup request for Amy after she sends 10 requests, and a cleanup request for Bob after he sends 10 requests?

Comment: So in your example, Amy need to run 10 POSTS and then Bob will run 1 POST to close out the first set of 10 ran by Amy. So that Amy can run another 10, followed by Bob(so on and so forth).

Comment: If Amy runs 10 POSTS, it has to be Bob, never Amy, who runs the close out POST?

Comment: No it could be Amy, I was using the names as a reference to the difference in POST calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use controllers to fulfill your requirements.

1. **Simple Controller** (POST request #1)
2. **Loop Controller** (Follow up requests) define # of times you want to execute inside loop controller
3. **Simple Controller** (Post request #2)

Let me know in case you need help on this.

Comment: This solution worked for me, my mistake was thinking I had to manage the loops within the thread group.